# SymPy ComplexInfinity

Tags: sympy

I have defined a piecewise function using sympy and took the integral using that piecewise function. After that the integral gives the following piecewise function

> Piecewise((zoo*x, x <= 0), (log(x) + oo, True))

As I want to implement this function to sympy.lambdify() function ıt gives the error

> KeyError: 'ComplexInfinity'

So my main purpose is to draw the graph of the first piecewise function but couldn't solve the error.
Also the following is my code and the full error message.

The Code:

```
> import sympy as sp
>
>from numpy import linspace
>
>import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
>
>
>x = sp.Symbol('x')
>
>
>def b(x):
>    p = sp.Piecewise((0, x <= 0), (x, x > 0))
>    return p
>
>
>load = sp.integrate(b(x)**-1,x)
>print(load)
>
>
>
>loadx = sp.lambdify(x, load, modules=["numpy"])
```

The Error Message:

```
    runfile('C:/Users/Mkaansa/Desktop/Piecewise.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mkaansa/Desktop')
Piecewise((zoo*x, x <= 0), (log(x) + oo, True))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\Desktop\Piecewise.py", line 28, in <module>
    loadx = sp.lambdify(x, load, modules=["numpy"])

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\lambdify.py", line 848, in lambdify
    funcstr = funcprinter.doprint(funcname, args, expr)

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\lambdify.py", line 1091, in doprint
    funcbody.append('return ({})'.format(self._exprrepr(expr)))

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\codeprinter.py", line 110, in doprint
    lines = self._print(expr).splitlines()

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\printer.py", line 329, in _print
    return getattr(self, printmethod)(expr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\numpy.py", line 152, in _print_Piecewise
    exprs = '[{}]'.format(','.join(self._print(arg.expr) for arg in expr.args))

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\numpy.py", line 152, in <genexpr>
    exprs = '[{}]'.format(','.join(self._print(arg.expr) for arg in expr.args))

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\printer.py", line 329, in _print
    return getattr(self, printmethod)(expr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\codeprinter.py", line 490, in _print_Mul
    a_str = [self.parenthesize(x, prec) for x in a]

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\codeprinter.py", line 490, in <listcomp>
    a_str = [self.parenthesize(x, prec) for x in a]

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\str.py", line 35, in parenthesize
    return self._print(item)

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\printer.py", line 329, in _print
    return getattr(self, printmethod)(expr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pycode.py", line 233, in _print_ComplexInfinity
    return self._print_NaN(expr)

  File "C:\Users\Mkaansa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pycode.py", line 72, in _print_known_const
    known = self.known_constants[expr.__class__.__name__]

KeyError: 'ComplexInfinity'
```

Comment: What would you expect the integral of 1/0 to be?

Comment: The error comes from that the concept of complex infinity does not exist in Python. Defining your function like p = sp.Piecewise((sp.oo, x <= 0), (1/x, x > 0)) and integrate that rather than 1/b(x) may take you a bit further. But the problem is really that you try to integrate 1/0 (which in SymPy by definition is zoo).

Comment: You can replace the `zoo` with `subs` if you know what you want it to be e.g. `expr.subs(zoo, oo)`.

Comment: Iterating the result as the programme takes integral may be useful but I couldn't find a method for that. If you know a method how to manipulate partial functions can you explain? That would be so useful.